# When is .class file created?

Tags: java

How java is interpreted as well as compiled? Also when is .class file created between this compilation and interpretation?

Comment: [This](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-1996/jw-07-classfile.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that the Java interpreter uses .class files as its input, and .class files are machine object code for the Java Virtual Machine "hardware". The `javac` compiler compiles your .java sources into .class objects, and then the JavaVM can execute (interpret) those objects.

Comment: Do we lose a lot of performance power writing code that can be executed on any machine? I've done a lot of Fortran and I feel like I had to worry about the specific architecture of my machine and computing cluster to get good performance (with respect to run-time speed).

Comment: Any time you put extra software between the code you need to run and the hardware, there's going to be some performance loss; how much depends on the specific JVM you're using. Some JVMs are very simple, needing to re-interpret every instruction each time it sees it. Some use "JIT" (just in time compilation) to convert instructions to native code to gain performance at run time. Others perform "AOT" (ahead of time compilation) to get a bigger performance boost. In each case though, the virtual machine will have some overhead.

Comment: Something else to consider about the efficiency here, it's not directly caused by using the Java language at all. The term "Java" is used to describe both the language and the runtime environment, but its possible to compile Java to native code (such as with GNU's gcj compiler), and it's possible to use other langauges to compile into .class files for execution within a JVM.

Answer (score 1):

When class file is created ?

Answer-> 
A class file generated when the compiler starts the compilation and exactly at that time  a interpreter(JRE) generates class file. Interpreter decodes our coding into the binary codes(machine language) and this binary code is used by our system or any system(machine) or we can say any operating system like linux, ubntu, windows, fadora.

Comment: I don't think the runtime environment is generating any class file. The [Java programming language compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) does.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of the .class file is the compilation step, so there's nothing between the two.

The .java file is compiled to byte code that's stored in a .class file.  The .class file is interpreted by the JRE.